# Crystal Report gives error when publishing the project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I want to publish my Project Created in Visual Studio 2010. it was OK,before i add the Crystal Report, but after adding crystal report , it is not possible to publish it. this is the error i get

The install location for prerequisites has not been set to 'component vendor's web site' and the file 'Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_3.msi' in item 'SAP Crystal Reports Runtime Engine for .NET Framework 4.0' can not be located on disk. See Help for more information.

The install location for prerequisites has not been set to 'component vendor's web site' and the file 'Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_3.msi' in item 'SAP Crystal Reports Runtime Engine for .NET Framework 4.0' can not be located on disk. See Help for more information.

I have installed Crystal Report for Visual Studio 2010. but i don't have CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_3.msi and CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_3.msi in 
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0
what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

You can download those files from here

[SAP Crystal Reports, developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio: Updates & Runtime Downloads](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824)

And check out this link, maybe it solves your problem

[Crystal reports problem](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/576388/crystalplusreportplusnotplusworkpluswithplus-NETpl)

Comment: I had it all , before this post

Comment: and have you tried what is said in this post? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/448478aa-b8d3-4985-85c3-070d734bfe86/crystal-reports-prerequisites-for-clickonce-deployment?forum=vscrystalreports

Comment: Yes none of them could solve me problem. but I solved it. i copied two msi files manually in the path, then i could publish the project. but users get an error when running the report. so i have to run the msi file manually on their pc and the run the application.